# Floating images under each other while having diffrent heights

Tags: html, css, floating

The divs have the same width. I've tried to clear all images, without the wanted results.

```
<div id="results">
    <div id="7" class="foodDiv">
    <div id="8" class="foodDiv">
    <!--6 divs more-->
</div>
<div class="clear"> </div>
```

The CSS

```
.foodDiv{
    padding:0 4% 0 0;
    max-width:20%;
    background-color:#CCC;
    float:left;
}
```

[image: Divs in wrong position]

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/ - take a look at this.

Comment: I am not sure I understand correctly, but if I do, why not also use max-height value? edit: max-height value plus overflow:hidden;

Answer (score 0):

If the images will have a fixed width, one option is to layout the content in the form of columns such as:

CSS

```
.column{
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class=column>
  <div id="1" class="food"></div>
  <div id="3" class="food"></div>
  <div id="5" class="food"></div>
</div>
<div class=column>
  <div id="2" class="food"></div>
  <div id="4" class="food"></div>
  <div id="6" class="food"></div>
</div>
```

And then they will be placed one on top of the other and the columns laid out side by side.

If columns aren't an option then the only way to do it is with javascript using something like masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/